Exclude from URL from google custom search not working
I am trying to use a Google custom search engine to query images. I want to avoid copyrighted imaged so I added Getty and Alamy to the list of Sites to exclude. Unfortunately I keep getting links from  alamy. Is there something wrong in the patterns here?
The URL I got from the search query is for example
https://c8.alamy.com/compit/kwfhxc/autore-americano-della-fantascienza-bruce-sterling-durante-una-conferenza-a-torino-alla-fiera-del-libro-kwfhxc.jpg 

